# mySQL: Finding the most common values between two columns

Tags: mysql

There are two tables I'm working with: Targets table has mid, gid and miRNA table has mid, miRNA_name. (mid is the ID for miRNA, and gid is the ID for the gene).

I want to list the top 10 miRNAs with the most genes regulated in common. Each row should have miRNA id #1, miRNA name #1, miRNA id #2, miRNA name #2, and the number of genes in common.

Targets table ex:

```
mid    gid
1      1
1      297
1      305
2      198
2      209
3      209
3      297
```

miRNA table ex:

```
mid      name
1       hsa-miR-4711
2       hsa-miR-36
3       hsa-miR-54
```

I think I need to group the two tables by mid and then sort by gid. With this, I should find which mids have common gids and list them as specified in the select clause along with the # of common genes (count gid).

So far I have the following, but I'm not sure if it's the right approach. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance! :)

```
SELECT m.mid, m.name, n.mid, n.name, COUNT (*)
FROM (SELECT mid, gid FROM miRNA JOIN targets USING (mid)) as m
AND (SELECT mid, gid FROM miRNA JOIN targets USING (mid)) as n
WHERE COUNT(*)>1
GROUP BY gid
LIMIT 10;
```

The output should look like:

```
mid1    name1          mid2     name2         count
1       hsa-miR-4711   3        hsa-miR-54    297
2       hsa-miR-36     3        hsa-miR-54    209
```

Comment: Where does Python come in?

Comment: Sorry, I meant mySQL (I have to run it in python eventually)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to confirm... you only care about the TWO miRNA entries that have the most in-common.  So in essence, compare miRNA #1 with all gIDs for miRNA #2, gIDs for miRNA #3, etc..

and if m#7 has 7 genome ids in common with m#58, and m#23 has 6 in common with m#49, etc... down stream, but m#7 could also have 5 in common with m#38.  If so, your list of this example would show something like

```
miNRA7  (17's name)   miNRA 58  (58's name)   7
miNRA23 (23's name)   miNRA 49  (49's name)   6
miNRA7  (17's name)   miNRA 38  (38's name)   5
```

If this is the case, I would do a self-join of the joins to get those qualified, THEN get the names.  I would ensure your TARGETS table as an index on ( gid, mid ) as one index, not two separate ones.

```
select
      TopPairs.mid,
      m1.name as NRAName1,
      TopPairs.AltMID,
      m2.name as NRAName2,
      TopPairs.PairCount
   from
      ( select
              t1.mid,
              t2.mid as AltMID,
              count(*) as PairCount
           from
              Targets t1
                 JOIN Targets t2
                        t1.gid = t2.gid
                    AND t1.mid < t2.mid
           group by
              t1.mid, 
              t2.mid
           having
              count(*) > 1
           order by
              count(*) DESC
           limit 10 ) TopPairs
      JOIN miRNA m1
         on TopPairs.mid = m1.mid
      JOIN miRNA m2
         on TopPairs.AltMID = m2.mid
```

The JOIN to the "t2" alias (second instance) is explicitly on the matching gIDs first, but then only for those where the t2.mid is GREATER than the t1.mid.  This is so #1 gets compared to #2, #3, #4, etc, but never need to compare #2, #3 or #4 back to #1 since they will have already been done.

Only AFTER the genome comparisons are done and you have your finite list does that get joined to the named miNRA tables to grab the explicit names for output.  No need to get those details if you are throwing out 300k genome comparisons and keeping 10.  Get the 10, then join.

Comment: Yes, you're correct, I only care about the two miRNA entries that have the most # in common. I joined targets to targets just like you showed and then linked that joined table to the miRNA table and it worked. Thank you so much for your help! Your example was very useful. :)

Comment: @FrootLoops, glad it worked.  As a newbie, check out the Help -> Tour for site etiquette so users know when a question has a valid solution so it's not left "open" is if nothing worked.  Up-checking and marking with the checkbox indicates good to go... This worked for me.